# Can't Access salesforce Attachments raw/binary data in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, salesforce, native, salesforce-service-cloud

Hi i am working on Salesforce mobile.I have to view salesforce attachments in my iphone app.For that i got access token successfully.
Now i am trying to get attachments binary data from salesforce to my iphone app 
But unable to get I am getting this error

```
[{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]
```

Here is my code

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *blobRequest=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
    NSString *blobPost = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Authorization=OAuth%@",access_token];


    NSData *blobpostData = [blobPost dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *blobpostLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [blobpostData length]];

    NSURL *blobUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/data/v23.0/sobjects/Attachment/00P90000004TRoWEAW/Body"];

    [blobRequest setURL:blobUrl];
    [blobRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [blobRequest setValue:blobpostLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    [blobRequest setValue:@"Base64" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [blobRequest setHTTPBody:blobpostData];

    NSError *blobError;
    NSURLResponse *blobresponse;

    NSData *blobData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:blobRequest returningResponse:&blobresponse error:&blobError];
    NSString *dataresponse=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:blobData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi yogibhoi the error says it all, i think your session is expired,